# Fetching Data from API and displaying the data returned from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm learning to fetch data, but can't seem to get it right with React. I've got a demo API that returns JSON data in a browser, but when testing it as a function in an app I'm making, no luck, all help is greatly appreciated!

App

```
import FetchData from './FetchData';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FetchData />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

FetchData Component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const FetchData = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo')
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setData(data);
            });
    }, []);
    return (
        data.map(data => (
            <div key={data.id}>
                <h1>{data.symbol}</h1>
                <p>{data.price}</p>
            </div>
        );
            )
};

export default FetchData;
```

I would just like to just have the stock symbol and price render on the page.

The data returned from the API is:

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "IBM",
        "02. open": "160.5900",
        "03. high": "161.0800",
        "04. low": "159.5300",
        "05. price": "160.7800",
        "06. volume": "2982924",
        "07. latest trading day": "2023-12-21",
        "08. previous close": "160.0500",
        "09. change": "0.7300",
        "10. change percent": "0.4561%"
    }
}
```

The errors returned in the browser after running the app are:

ERROR

```
 in ./src/FetchData.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/jamiekayam/api-data-call-app/src/FetchData.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (21:9)

  19 |                 <p>{data.price}</p>
  20 |             </div>
> 21 |         );
     |          ^
  22 |             )
  23 | };
  24 |
```

ERROR

```
[eslint] 
src/FetchData.jsx
  Line 21:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (21:9)
```

Comment: remove the `;` - it's not valid syntax to put it there - the problem is obfuscated by your poor indentation - there's also a missing `)` in that part of the code